# How can I make my Video play as soon as the page loads

Tags: javascript, swfobject, flvplayback

im lost here, need some help for something probably very simple:

I have embedded a swf object to play an flv file. i want the video to play as soon as the page loads rather than requiring the viewer/user to have to click the play button to see the video.

I'm not sure if it is the swf file, the script or the javascipt file that has to be edited, and with what code.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to consult the documentation of the player `.swf` you're using for that. If you want further information, at least mention which player you're using...

Comment: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/11172/how-can-i-make-the-jw-player-autoplay#comment-75719

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/11172/how-can-i-make-the-jw-player-autoplay#comment-75719